# How to change selected item in a combobox

Tags: jquery, jira

I have an application (JIRA), that has a combobox implemented with an `input` tag and attributes `role="combobox"`, `aria-autocomplete="list"` plus a list of `li` tags with `role="option"`

I need to set the default selected option to one of the li options, but I don't know how to do this with this implementation. When using select and option tags there is an attribute (selected) to handle this, but how can I do this with this implementation?

Comment: Select any particular option with mouse and after doing that open the browser's developer's console and check which all attributes are getting added to the combobox's HTML. Once you know that, try adding same with code.

Comment: @user1821991 can you please add the `html` code of that `li`

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the input tag: https://casari-asoc.mangoapps.com/sf/NjkxMDRfMTU2MjI2MA and the options: https://casari-asoc.mangoapps.com/sf/NjkxMDNfMTU2MjI1OQ